# Creating machine-readable name before persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony2/Doctrine project, I have an Entity called `Developer` including those fields in particular:

```
 1. firstName
 2. lastName
 3. machineName
```

The form to create a Developer item only shows firstName and lastName fields. I'd like the machineName to be automatically generated when the user creates a Developer item, based on the two other fields.

For instance, `John Doe` would give `john_doe` and `Jérémy Arçouille` would give `jeremy_arcouille`.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is there a general best practice for this (pretty common) case?
2. Do I have to code something from my own or is it something pretty standard?
3. If (2 == true) what would be the best place (services? utils?) to put that trunk of code?
4. Should I rather call this portion of code from the controller or from the entity?

*Note: because it would be quite a portion of code, and I'd like it to be reusable, I don't want to put into a prePersist lifecycle callback*

I once developed a full solution for this problem and it worked well, but was really lame and spaghetti-esque, so I'd rather make something more in the proper Symfony2 way by now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 for writing the question quite clearly

Comment: You could create a service and inject it into a lifecycle callback listener service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two approaches you could try in this case.

1. Create [`prePresists` event listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners). This solution is very easy to implement, works transparently from the application point of view and can be used with existing code.

   1. Define your listener service:

      ```
      use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
      use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
      use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

      class MyEventListener implements EventSubscriber
      {
          public function __construct(/* ... */)
          {
              /* you can use other services here */
          }

          public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
          {
              $developer = $event->getEntity();

              if (!($developer instanceof Developer) || $developer->hasMachineName()) {
                  return;
              }

              ...
              $developer->setMachineName(...);
          }

          public function getSubscribedEvents()
          {
              return array(Events::prePersist);
          }
      }
      ```
   2. Declare it in Symofny's service container

      ```
      <service id="..." class="...">
          <!-- <argument ... /> -->
          <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber" />
      </service>
      ```
   3. You're done.
2. Create appropriate domain/bussines layer for your application. This requires more work, forces you to follow some general guidelines but makes your code much more flexible and easy to maintain. In a nutshell, instead of using Doctrine's ObjectManager directly inside your controllers create a whole new layer of servers dedicated to work with your domain objects. This layer sholud contain, among others, a service that's responsible for persisting developers with `save(Developer $dev)` method. This method should do exactly the same job as `MyEventListener` from first approach.

PS. You shouldn't do any complex operations or refer to external classes from within your entities.

Comment: Many thanks! Is there some resource/guide/tutorial about your point #2 that you could redirect me to? I'm asking this because this concept of appropriate domain/business layer sounds interesting and I'd like to learn more about this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what I came up with for the moment.

I created a class file in MyBundle\Utils\MachinesNames.php, containing a method called by Developer entity's class:

```
// MyBundle\Utils\MachineNames.php
class MachinesNames
{
    public static function createDeveloperName(array $nameArray)
    {
        // code goes here

        return $machineName;
    }

    public static function createActivityName(array $nameArray)
    {
        // other stuff...

        return $machineName;
    }
}


// MyBundle\Entity\Developer.php
class Developer
{
    public function setMachineName()
    {
        $nameArray = array(
            'firstName' => $this->getFirstName(),
            'lastName' => $this->getLastName(),
        );

        $machineName = MachineNames::createDeveloperName($nameArray);

        $this->setName($machineName);
    }
}
```

This function is called on prePersist with a lifecycle callback.

Any remarks? Is there a better way? How would you have done this?

Comment: You can use php iconv: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'è');`